# Simple modal relative to container div

Tags: jquery, css, simplemodal

I am using `simplemodal` ([www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)) in multiple locations for a site.  I need to set some of these relative to the copy container div 1000px. Is this possible? Or can they only be set to the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your simplemodal html element is a child of a container, and said container has relative or absolute positioning then you can pull it off.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Edit: Since your real goal is custom positioning. Just utilize the ability the dev provided in the library to manually position the modal. This is taken straight out of the documentation.

```
// Manually set position using percentages
$("#sample").modal({position: ["50%","50%"]});
```

In order to position it correctly, you just need to get the offset of the element you want to position over, above, below, adjacent to etc... and perform the simple math and then call set the position as demonstrated above.

You can get the offset of any element like so:

```
var os = $('#selector').offset();
var top = os.top;
var left = os.left;
```

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

The offset is relative to the entire document so it will serve your fixed positioning needs well I believe.

Comment: I have the modal set relative to the container div however simplemodal add's `code` position: fixed; z-index: 1002; height: 600px; width: 700px; left: 100px; top: 100px; `code` you can give a left:100px and top:100px but it still display's relative to the body not the container. That I need.

Comment: @esoteric You basically don't want it to auto position itself then? Is that what you are really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to display the popup directly below specific elements

Comment: @esoteric Well silly, you should have read the documentation! =P The dev provides a method for manually positioning an element. See my edited answer

Comment: Your right, thank you, I really appreciate the help.  I was using the position but the offset was the key.

Comment: @esoteric Np, glad to help. Feel free to upvote/mark as answered if this solved your problem (as is the long standing tradtion here on Stackoverflow). =P

Answer (score 1):

This answer isn't specific to simplemodal, but rather a general CSS rule. If the parent container is position:relative, then the children can be positioned relative to the parent. Example:

```
     <div style="position: relative;">
          <div style="position: absolute; top: -100px; left: -100px;">
               This div is 100 pixels up and left of the parent div
          </div>
     </div>
```

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: This rule also applies if the parent is absolutely positioned.

Comment: Thanks Matt that works in most cases, but not with the simplemodal. I have the modal set relative to the container div however simplemodal add's `code` position: fixed; z-index: 1002; height: 600px; width: 700px; left: 100px; top: 100px; `code` you can give a left:100px and top:100px but it still display's relative to the body not the container. That I need.

Comment: It occurs to me that simplemodal might append the modal to the body tag, which means that it will always be relative to the body. I have no experience with simplemodal (I have my own class that I use), but perhaps it has a way for you to customize the location of the modal. Check out its documentation for custom x/y coordinates. Good luck.